# convert c# TripleDes PKCS7 code to php code

Tags: c#, php, pkcs#7, tripledes

I have this code in C#

```
var dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes('clear text');

var symmetric = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create("TripleDes");
symmetric.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
symmetric.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

var encryptor = symmetric.CreateEncryptor(Convert.FromBase64String('myKey'), new byte[8]);

var signedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length));
```

now i need convert c# code to php code.
regard

Comment: It is best not to use 3DES, it is antiquated and not very secure, instead use AES. Do not use ECB mode, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use this function and worked for me

```
function encryptData($plainText,$key)
{

    $byte = mb_convert_encoding($key, 'ASCII');

    $desKey = base64_decode($key);
    $data = mb_convert_encoding($plainText, 'ASCII');

    // add PKCS#7 padding
    $blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $paddingSize = $blocksize - (strlen($data) % $blocksize);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($paddingSize), $paddingSize);

    // encrypt password
    $encData = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $desKey, $data, 'ecb');

    return base64_encode($encData);
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to believe that `$key` or `$plainText` can be converted to `ASCII`. A better encoding would be `utf8`.